# Loop for function names

Tags: c

I will make my question short and simple:

I have a series of functions called f1, f2, f3 etc. and now I want to loop through them, not typing them one by one. Is there a way to do this? It is a c programming practice.

Comment: Have you made single try to write code for this ? Have You done any research.If yes post your code. else this not place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection doesn't work in C, as far i Know, So you cannot dynamically convert string to function calls, using their names.

However, you can use function pointers to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1()
{
   printf("f1() \n");
   return 0;
}

int f2()
{
   printf("f2() \n");
   return 0;
}

int f3()
{
   printf("f3() \n");
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int (*p[3])() = {
      f1,
      f2,
      f3
   };

   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      (*p[i]) ();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is helpful, but the function names are given in another c file, so I can't redefine them.

Comment: You can always include that file. You don't need to redefine them.

Comment: You are not redefining them, just pointing to them by address.

Comment: Yes, I included that file, and just have no idea how to call them by loop.

Comment: I am calling from main, then the function calls another function which is in another file.

Comment: Compile with C99 or later.

Answer (score 0):

If you you are looking for a function to convert function name string to the address, try dlsym()

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html